# Average dimensions of the human back (anthropometry)

Tags: human-anatomy

I am wondering if anyone can point me to (a scientific source that provides) the estimates of the dimensions (length x width) of the human back?

I am specifically interested in the dimensions (**length * width**, or surface) of the **lower back** of the average adult, and in specific the region between the 7<sup>th</sup> thoracic and 4<sup>th</sup> lumbar vertebra - i.e., the region between T7 - L4 in the image below:

Ideally a distinction is made between males and females and perhaps kids as well. The area of research dealing with this matter is anthropometry.

[image: back]

Please mention the source to any information provided. I have access to some not-scientifically based sources (clothing companies for example). Although additional such sources are welcomed, scientifically-based answers are preferred.

Comment: Although not very related, this set of drawings is very interesting: http://www.jneuhaus.com/human.html

Comment: http://brml.technion.ac.il/publications_files/1195633781.pdf

Comment: Here they give the dimensions of the entire back, if that interests you: http://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section03.htm#_3.3_ANTHROPOMETRIC_AND

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question and I only post it at the asker's request.

[NASA has measured the dimensions of the back in 40 year old American males and 40 year old Japanese females in the year 2000 at 1G.](http://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section03.htm%23_3.3_ANTHROPOMETRIC_AND) Of course gravity matters to NASA…

[image]

From figure 3.3.1.3-1 (American male). All data in centimetres:

- 921 Waist back

  - 5th percentile: 43.7
  - 50th percentile: 47.6
  - 95th percentile: 51.6
- 506 Interscye

  - 5th percentile: 32.9
  - 50th percentile: 39.2
  - 95th percentile: 45.4